# How to get result of this script?

Tags: javascript, php, countdown

This is simple countdown script, but I can't get result of this, you definitely see answer as soon you look on it. please safe my time and help me masters.

This is Javascript of making all this happen

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function eventstime(lasttime, repeattime, showid, opentime) {
    if (lasttime < 0) lasttime = repeattime-1;
    if (lasttime <= opentime) {
        document.getElementById(showid).innerHTML = "is Open";
        setTimeout('eventstime('+(lasttime-1)+', '+repeattime+', \''+showid+'\', '+opentime+');', 999);
    } else {
        var secs = lasttime % 60;
        if (secs < 10) secs = '0'+secs;
        var lasttime1 = (lasttime - secs) / 60;
        var mins = lasttime1 % 60;
        if (mins < 10) mins = '0'+mins;
        lasttime1 = (lasttime1 - mins) / 60;
        var hours = lasttime1 % 24;
        var days = (lasttime1 - hours) / 24;
        if (days > 1) days = days+' days + ';
        else if (days > 0) days = days+' day + ';
        document.getElementById(showid).innerHTML = days+hours+':'+mins+':'+secs;
        setTimeout('eventstime('+(lasttime-1)+', '+repeattime+', \''+showid+'\', '+opentime+');', 999);
    }
}
</script>
```

This is unfinished result of event.

```
  $i = 0;
    echo '';
    foreach ($eventtime as $value) {
        $i++;
        $bc_remain = $value['repeattime'] - ((WEBSITE_REAL_TIME - strtotime($value['start'])) % $value['repeattime']);
        $startevents .= 'eventstime('.$bc_remain.', '.$value['repeattime'].', \'event'.$i.'\', '.$value['opentime'].'); ';
        echo '<tr><td align="right">'.$value['name'].':</td><td id="event'.$i.'"></td></tr>';
    }
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'.$startevents.'</script>';
```

And finally this you can call configure

```
<?php
$eventtime[1]['name']   = 'Blood Castle';
$eventtime[1]['start']      = 'Jan 01,  2011 00:19:00';
$eventtime[1]['repeattime'] = '3600';
$eventtime[1]['opentime']   = '300';

$eventtime[2]['name']   = 'Devil Square';
$eventtime[2]['start']      = 'Jan 01,  2011 01:00:00';
$eventtime[2]['repeattime'] = '7200';
$eventtime[2]['opentime']   = '300';

$eventtime[3]['name']   = 'Castle Siage';
$eventtime[3]['start']      = 'Jan 01,  2011 00:00:00';
$eventtime[3]['repeattime'] = '7200';
$eventtime[3]['opentime']   = '300';

$eventtime[4]['name']   = 'Shadow';
$eventtime[4]['start']      = 'Jan 01,  2011 01:00:00';
$eventtime[4]['repeattime'] = '500';
$eventtime[4]['opentime']   = '300';

$eventtime[5]['name']   = 'Lucky Hour';
$eventtime[5]['start']      = 'Jan 01,  2011 01:05:00';
$eventtime[5]['repeattime'] = '800';
$eventtime[5]['opentime']   = '300';

$eventtime[6]['name']   = 'Blue';
$eventtime[6]['start']      = 'Jan 01,  2011 01:00:00';
$eventtime[6]['repeattime'] = '3900';
$eventtime[6]['opentime']   = '300';

define('WEBSITE_REAL_TIME', time());
```

I know its simple, but please give quick hand.

Comment: It would appear you're mixing javascript and php in a way that is very hard to follow. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you may want to have php echo html elements with data attributes and then run the javascript on that rather than php echoing javascript functions.

Comment: i want simply get result of this, result means - code after doing all this what is above, give some kind a result, i`m asking you for tools, show me this tools how to pull out this result. can you?

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Here you go. You really just need to echo some `<table>` elements around your foreach loop to get something on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function eventstime(lasttime, repeattime, showid, opentime) {
    if (lasttime < 0) lasttime = repeattime-1;
    if (lasttime <= opentime) {
        document.getElementById(showid).innerHTML = "is Open";
        setTimeout('eventstime('+(lasttime-1)+', '+repeattime+', \''+showid+'\', '+opentime+');', 999);
    } else {
        var secs = lasttime % 60;
        if (secs < 10) secs = '0'+secs;
        var lasttime1 = (lasttime - secs) / 60;
        var mins = lasttime1 % 60;
        if (mins < 10) mins = '0'+mins;
        lasttime1 = (lasttime1 - mins) / 60;
        var hours = lasttime1 % 24;
        var days = (lasttime1 - hours) / 24;
        if (days > 1) days = days+' days + ';
        else if (days > 0) days = days+' day + ';
        document.getElementById(showid).innerHTML = days+hours+':'+mins+':'+secs;
        setTimeout('eventstime('+(lasttime-1)+', '+repeattime+', \''+showid+'\', '+opentime+');', 999);
    }
}
</script>


<?php
$eventtime[1]['name']   = 'Blood Castle';
$eventtime[1]['start']      = 'Jan 01,  2011 00:19:00';
$eventtime[1]['repeattime'] = '3600';
$eventtime[1]['opentime']   = '300';

$eventtime[2]['name']   = 'Devil Square';
$eventtime[2]['start']      = 'Jan 01,  2011 01:00:00';
$eventtime[2]['repeattime'] = '7200';
$eventtime[2]['opentime']   = '300';

$eventtime[3]['name']   = 'Castle Siage';
$eventtime[3]['start']      = 'Jan 01,  2011 00:00:00';
$eventtime[3]['repeattime'] = '7200';
$eventtime[3]['opentime']   = '300';

$eventtime[4]['name']   = 'Shadow';
$eventtime[4]['start']      = 'Jan 01,  2011 01:00:00';
$eventtime[4]['repeattime'] = '500';
$eventtime[4]['opentime']   = '300';

$eventtime[5]['name']   = 'Lucky Hour';
$eventtime[5]['start']      = 'Jan 01,  2011 01:05:00';
$eventtime[5]['repeattime'] = '800';
$eventtime[5]['opentime']   = '300';

$eventtime[6]['name']   = 'Blue';
$eventtime[6]['start']      = 'Jan 01,  2011 01:00:00';
$eventtime[6]['repeattime'] = '3900';
$eventtime[6]['opentime']   = '300';

define('WEBSITE_REAL_TIME', time());




$i = 0;
   echo '<table>';
   foreach ($eventtime as $value) {
       $i++;
       $bc_remain = $value['repeattime'] - ((WEBSITE_REAL_TIME - strtotime($value['start'])) % $value['repeattime']);
       $startevents .= 'eventstime('.$bc_remain.', '.$value['repeattime'].', \'event'.$i.'\', '.$value['opentime'].'); ';
       echo '<tr><td align="right">'.$value['name'].':</td><td id="event'.$i.'"></td></tr>';
   }
   echo '</table>';
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">'.$startevents.'</script>';

 ?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot buddy. Last question, how to pull out all $eventtime[1-6] all on list?

Comment: It shows clearly and correct 1 , but all other 2-6  $eventtime[2]['name']  shows only first half <tr><td align="right">'.$value['name'].': </td> and second half dont - show <td id="event'.$i.'"></td></tr>';

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The names show on the left and the timer thing is on the right.

Comment: yes but just for first, for second and till 6 dont show a result. maybe somhow can indicate '.$startevents[2].' or......?

Comment: That sounds like a css issue. I see all 6.

Comment: If you know how to run php in jsfiddle, then please post a link here. Otherwise, no.